# Can we test or evaluate entity extraction in Rasa NLU?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu

Is it possible to evaluate how well my model extracts entities (and maps synonym values) in Rasa NLU?

I have tried the `rasa_nlu -evaluate` mode however, it seems to only work for intent classification, although my JSON data file contains entities information and I'd really like to know if my entity extraction is up to the mark given various scenarios. I've used Tracy to generate test dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes - you should get the score to you entities as well.
Are you sure you added some to your training data?

do you have it NER algo that fetches them? something like this?

```
pipeline:
- name: "intent_featurizer_count_vectors"
- name: "intent_classifier_tensorflow_embedding"
  batch_size: 64
  epochs: 1500
- name: "nlp_spacy"
- name: "tokenizer_spacy"
- name: "ner_crf"
```

`ner_crf` is conditional random field for extracting the "name entity recognition"

To make sure you follow the model building correctly have a look at this tutorial:
https://hackernoon.com/build-simple-chatbot-with-rasa-part-1-f4c6d5bb1aea

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/0.12.0/evaluation/, if your are using either `ner_crf` or `ner_duckling`, the evaluation method automatically takes entity extraction performance unto account. If you only use `ner_synonyms` the evaluate method won't compute an output table.

Other possible pitfalls could be:

If you parse a single sentence including a desired entity, does your trained model extract an entity? This could be a clue to the situation that your model was not able to evolve a pattern recognizing entities.

Also a problem could be that by randomly splitting the data into train and test set, there's no entity in your test set to extract. Your algorithm could have learned the pattern but is not forced to apply this pattern. Did you check wether your test set contains entities?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, perhaps you are interested in something like https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/issues/1472?  So, this issue was written because for intents you could get overall score and you could see how each intent was classified, but you could only get the overall score for entities and not how each entity was classified.

So in short, this is still an open issue and not possible in Rasa.  However, it was an issue I was asked to look at just yesterday, so I will let you know if I make any progress on it.